# White list of BLE connections in ESP32 using arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I am working on ESP32 in Arduino IDE to scan for BLE advertising devices. I want to only look for my known BLE devices. For these known devices I wanted to white list them.  Can anyone please guide me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need further information: 
1. Are you using connectable advertisements or non connectable advertisements.
2. Does your advertising device include some UUIDs/manufacture specific data in the advertising packet?
3. If at anypoint of time you are connecting to the device, Do you use pairing and bonding?

Comment: Thank you chirag Parekh for answering on it. My devices are wearable hand bands which does non connectable advertisements. These devices advertises the MAC ID and UUID. I am not pairing to them. Using a library I am just getting these values on a scan. A list of devices for which I need to scan, I wanted to whitelist them.

Comment: Since you are using non connectable advertisements, it wont be possible for you to white list the devices. Based on the advertisements received you have to filter the devices based on the advertisement data. You can use the service UUIDs advertised by the hand bands or you can customize the hand bands advertising data and add manufacture specific data over which filtering can be applied.